# How to scale icons by zoom in a MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit, mkmapview

How can I have the size of my icons scale with zoom in a `MKMapView`? As far as I can tell there is no way to do this?

The only thing I can think of is to have the `MKMapView` a subview of some `UIView`, and catch all of the user input in this parent view, scale the images on zoom and relay to the subview.

Comment: When you say icons, do you mean annotations?  As in MKAnnotationView?

Comment: Well I am trying this technique out right now trying to extend MKMapView to add this functionality, we will see how it goes.

Comment: Did you get this working? I'm trying something else involving extending MKMapView for a similar reason, and was wondering whether you could share how that worked for you...

Comment: Yes I was able to get this working quite effectively. I will write a post about it on my blog and send you the link. Probably within a week or so.

Comment: Did you post the article? Can't find your blog.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a `CGTransform` on the annotation views on each `mapRegionChanged`